# Run script recursively

Tags: recursive

I have a script that will concat and rename the video files in a folder which I have pieced together using tips from StackExchange.

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -d $PWD/* >> file.txt
sed -i "s/^\|$/'/g" file.txt
sed -i -e 's_.*_file &_' file.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i file.txt -c copy ${PWD##*/}.mp4
```

I would like to run this recursively, which would seem to involve using the `find` command, but I am a little wary of messing this up and losing a load of data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess it would help if you provide an example directory hierarchy and explain what the result is supposed to be (i.e. what exactly the `ffmpeg` call(s) shall look like). However, you need only one `sed` call: `sed "s/.*/file '&'/"` And you should use quotes: `ls -d "$PWD"/*`, `"${PWD##*/}".mp4`

Comment: If you want manual checks to make sure nothing is messed up, I suggest using two steps: Replace the `ls` with `find`, and do the two `sed` as first step. Then manually inspect `file.txt`. Finally run `ffmpeg` on `file.txt` if the manual inspection is ok.

Comment: also, copy a small subset of your directory hierarchy to another directory and work on that.  if you mess it up, just delete the mess and copy the subset again.   alternatively, write your output files to a different directory - again, delete if it fails, fix any bugs in your script, and run again.   As a general rule: when doing anything potentially destructive, **NEVER** work on your only copy of the data. At the very least, make a backup so you can restore it in case of something going wrong.